# Algorithm to place the rectangular inside the polygon

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, computational-geometry

Is there any algorithm that can place an arbitrary rectangular inside an arbitrary polygon (I can deal with limitation to only convex polygons) in the closest available position (i.e. without intersections with polygon)?

[image]

For example, an algorithm should move the rectangular from image above to this position:
[image]

It's important, that I don't know original position of rectangular before it leaves the polygon. So I should find most close available position in the polygon.

Comment: This should be easy with [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). You are looking for a translation vector `v = (vx, vy)` of minimal norm such that the four corners of the rectangle are inside the polygon. "Inside the polygon" can be translated into a set of 2n linear inequations, where n is the number of sides of the polygon: each side of the polygon gives an inequation that means "above this line" (or "under this line").

Comment: Note that in the case of a non-convex polygon, it is possible for all 4 corners of the rectangle to be inside the polygon, while some part of the rectangle is outside of the polygon; but in the case of a convex polygon, if the four corners of the rectangle are inside, then all the rectangle is inside.

Comment: I recommend [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) to solve the resulting minimisation problem.

Comment: I'm slightly familiar with linear programming, but I don't know even what I should do with non negativity constraints and what's objective function here? It's not linear at all, because the length is not linear: l(v) = sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2)

Comment: @Stef You probably meant [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), but that might be overkill here (and only works with convex polygon). Instead, compute the [Minkowski difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) between the polygon and the rectangle, then compute the closest point of that to the "pivot" point in the polygon. (not sure what the complexity would be)

Comment: @user202729, do you know the algorithm for Minkowski difference calculation? I see that  some people use A - B = A + (-B), but it's incorrect in the general case

Comment: @user202729 I'm doing it right now. Thank you for the idea, anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for convex polygons I believe there's a fairly simple solution which involves constructing the inset polygon representing the loci of the rectangle's center point when the rectangle is just touching the polygon.

A diagram will hopefully help - the blue polygon represents the input polygon, the red the inner polygon that we need to construct.

[image]

Once we have this inner polygon we can just locate the point closest to the center of the rectangle and translate the rectangle's center to coincide with this point. If the inner polygon contains the center of the rectangle then you can choose between leaving it untouched or translating it outwards so that it touches the outer polygon.

[image]

The inner polygon can be constructed by insetting each side of the input polygon by a distance equal to half the angular width of the rectangle, and determining the intersection points of neighboring inset sides. If a side of the outer polygon is it angle `a` to the positive x axis then the inset distance is as shown below. Note that we'll have to ensure that `a` lies in the first quadrant, possibly swapping the width and height of the rectangle if this is not the case.

[image]

Once we have the inset distances for neighboring sides we can calculate the corresponding point on the inner polygon as shown below, where `b` is the angle between the neighboring sides and `p'` is the calculated point.

[image]

Here's some Java code to illustrate - we assume the input polygon is ordered counter-clockwise, such that the interior is to the left as we travel around the sides.

```java
List<Point2D> poly = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(p(0, 0), p(10, 0), p(13, 7), p(9, 12), p(4, 15), p(-3, 11), p(-5, 6)));

List<Point2D> innerPoly = new ArrayList<>();
            
int n = poly.size();
for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<n; j=i++)
{
    Point2D p0 = poly.get(j);
    Point2D p1 = poly.get(i);
    Point2D p2 = poly.get((i+1) % n);
    
    Point2D u0 = unit(p0, p1);
    Point2D u1 = unit(p1, p2);
    
    double d0 = rectAngDist(u0, outerRect);
    double d1 = rectAngDist(u1, outerRect);
    
    double phi = Math.PI - angle(u0, u1);
    
    double v0 = d0 / Math.sin(phi);
    double v1 = d1 / Math.sin(phi);

    innerPoly.add(add(p1, add(times(u0, -v1), times(u1, v0))));
}

static double rectAngDist(Point2D u, Rectangle2D r)
{
    double w = r.getWidth();
    double h = r.getHeight();
    
    double s0 = w;
    double s1 = h;
    
    double th0 = angle(u);
    if(th0 < 0) th0 += Math.PI;
    if(th0 > Math.PI/2) 
    {
        s0 = h; s1 = w; 
        th0 -= Math.PI/2;
    }               
    
    return (s0 * Math.sin(th0) + s1 * Math.cos(th0))/2;         
}
```

Once we have the inner polygon we can identify the closest point and translate the rectangle to coincide.

```java
Point2D centre = p(outerRect.getCenterX(), outerRect.getCenterY());
if(innerPoly.contains(centre))
{
    innerRect.setFrame(outerRect);
    return;
}
            
double minDist = 0;
Point2D closestPoint = null;
for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<n; j=i++)
{
    Point2D p0 = innerPoly.get(j);
    Point2D p1 = innerPoly.get(i);
    
    double len = distance(p0, p1);              
    Point2D u = unit(p0, p1);               
    
    Point2D diff = sub(centre, p0);             
    double s = dot(u, diff);
    
    Point2D pp = (s < 0) ? p0 : (s > len) ? p1 : add(p0, times(u, s));  
    
    double dist = distance(pp, centre);             
    if(closestPoint == null || dist < minDist)
    {
        closestPoint = pp;
        minDist = dist;
    }
}

translate(outerRect, sub(closestPoint, centre), innerRect);
```

I implemented the above in Java to test out the ideas - you can watch a short capture of the application in operation here ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmTrfJCj4J8)).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a nice and detailed answer!

Comment: The method also works for concave polygons, though the construction is more complex. The operation is a Minkowski difference.

Comment: I am not sure that your solution is valid when a side is shorter than the sides of the rectangle.